# How I can play a Youtube video on a platform that is not Android, IOS, Web?

Tags: video, youtube, playing

I would like playing Youtube video by my own program.
Unfortunately, I found that "Play Youtube Video API" just supports Android, IOS, and Web (IFrame), and my program does not run on those platforms.

I have just found only 1 solution until now.
I retrieve the "download link" of a video via get_video_info.
For example, this is a link that I got:

http://r8---sn-42u-nbor.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?fexp=9408086%2C9413209%2C9416126%2C9416891%2C9419452%2C9422596%2C9428398%2C9429854%2C9431012%2C9433096%2C9433380%2C9433946%2C9435526%2C9435876%2C9436618%2C9437066%2C9437553%2C9438663%2C9438697%2C9439652%2C9439818%2C9439885%2C9440878&***expire=1467991919***&lmt=1450948590440899&ip=210.245.31.23&key=yt6&ms=au&mv=m&source=youtube&id=o-AGJZH_QZDqM37AUvkGw-vb8K-kRvxZeO11rd3pE3Rgnm&dur=38366.818&mn=sn-42u-nbor&upn=diBdVgDBQmw&signature=20F8392E3097925E38B41B1B7E2D8CC85015CBE7.A1BC6E2E2ECA8368A646E00919A303065AAEC011&mm=31&initcwndbps=1897500&mime=video%2Fmp4&itag=18&sver=3&pl=24&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&mt=1467969960&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&signature=&type=video/mp4;%20codecs=%22avc1.42001E,%20mp4a.40.2%22&title=NCS%20Music%20Non%20Stop%2010%20Hours

However, I found this link will expire couple hours later.

I would like to know:

- How can I know the link is about to expire? I found "expire" param in the link:
  ***expire=1467991919***
  So what does it mean? What it the unit of the number ***1467991919***?
- Or, Is there any solution for playing Youtube video on a platform that is not Android, IOS, Web?

Thank you very much:)

Comment: Only a partial answer: 1467991919 is a timestamp in seconds since January 1 1970, and represents the date & time 8 July 2016 15:31:59 GMT.